# Why we use model = User in class Meta When we customize our UserCreationForm or AuthenticationForm in django?

Tags: django

- I am unable to give labels in class Meta these fields *username*,
  *password1* and *password2*, I can only modify these fields in outside class Meta, why?
- And why we use model = User while we are overriding our
  UserCreationForm?

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import widgets

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,label="Confirm Password")
    class Meta:
        model = User   #why we use User here 
        fields = ["username", "first_name", "last_name", "email"]
        labels = {"email": "Email" }
```

Comment: Try to create custom user model and then use it in signup form